# Changing Gas Price value in Metamask input field with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, metamask

I need to change the Gas Price value in Metamask extension using JS.

What i do:

I open Metamask in separate browser tab and run my JS script in its console - script detects if any new transaction is appeared and clicks the "Edit" gas fee link, after that a window with Gas Limit and Gas Price input fields appears.

There i get the Gas Price input field element in a variable `input_field` and change (increase) its value (`input_field.value = 10`).
Visually input field changes its value at this step.

But after clicking the "Save" button Gas Price value returns to previous.

So i suppose there some function which i have to run after new gas price value assignment, but can't find which one.

Can anyone help with resolving this?

Comment: Show us some code, how do you expect us to resolve this without the code?

Comment: this question should be asked in the Ethereum Stack Exchange, you'll also have to specify what library you're using and improve your question

Comment: really all the code is:
```input_field.value = 10;
save_button.click();```

and i don't use any libraries

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I'm having the same problem!